# How can count different duplicates

Tags: python-3.x

I shared code below;
I want delete duplicates  and count them.Also want a column for count times.
So clearly that code will count A column and count,delete duplicates.Finally it will add as a new column. Is it possible somehow?

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"]})

---

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo","bar"], "B":[3,1]})

Answer (score 0):

While completely not using pandas, you could achieve this using Counter from standard collections:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"])
>>> counter = Counter(["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"])
>>> counter.keys()
dict_keys(['foo', 'bar'])
>>> counter.values()
dict_values([3, 1])
```

So, for your case:

```
counter = Counter(["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"])
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": list(counter.keys()), "B": list(counter.values())})
```